# Nextjs how to get visitor ipconfig information

Tags: next.js, ip

I am currently develop a nextjs app and I want to create a white list of ip that can access some pages, I already obtain the public ip via request. But I also want to get the ip of the visitor device only. Is there a way to do so?

I have tried this but its only return public ip

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // Clone the request headers so that we don't modify the original headers object
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);

  // Check if the hosting platform provides the client's IP address and store it in a variable
  let ip: any = request.ip ?? request.headers.get("x-real-ip");
  const forwardedFor: any =
    request.ip ?? request.headers.get("x-forwarded-for");
  // Add the client's IP address to the request headers using the 'x-forwarded-for' field
  requestHeaders.set("x-real-ip", ip);
  requestHeaders.set("x-forwarded-for", forwardedFor);
  // Return a new request object with the updated headers using NextResponse.next()
  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
}
```